# Formula to show multiple values

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Trying to find a formula that would allow me to show certain values.

Example:

I want to see Aspirin and Warfarin and (one or more of the next 3 values) Clopidogrel or Prasugrel or Ticagrelor.

Patient1 takes:

Aspirin
Warfarin 
Clopidgrel

Patient 2 takes:
Aspirin
Warfarin

Right now I am seeing both patient 1 and patient 2 and I only want to see patients like patient 1 that shows the 3 different medications.

Please help and thank you in advance.  I am using crystal reports 2008.

Comment: Are you looking for a **selection** formula, so that the report only returns those patients that match the conditions specified? Also, are you reporting from a relational data source, and if so, which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, etc.) is it? (This type of selection can be done in Crystal, but is easier and likely to be more efficient in SQL.)

Comment: Selection formula and we use the Oracle as the data source.

Comment: What would be another formula that is not SQL.  Just wanted to be able to have options.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how this can be achieved in Crystal, without amending the SQL.

Comment: Thank you Mark Bannister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding something like the following lines to the SQL select clause:

```
count(distinct case when medication in ('Aspirin', 'Warfarin') 
                    then medication end) 
     over (partition by patient) as mandatory_meds,
count(distinct case when medication in ('Clopidogrel', 'Prasugrel', 'Ticagrelor')
                    then medication end) 
     over (partition by patient) optional_meds,
```

- then adding the following conditions to the SQL where clause:

```
and mandatory_meds = 2 and optional_meds >= 1
```

Alternatively, you could achieve a similar result in Crystal by:

- group the report by patient
- create a crystal formula called mandatory_meds, with a formula like: 
  `if {myTable.medication} = "Aspirin" or {myTable.medication} = "Warfarin"` 
  `then {myTable.medication}`
- create a crystal formula called optional_meds, with a formula like: 
  `if {myTable.medication} = "Clopidogrel" or {myTable.medication} = "Prasugrel"`
  `or {myTable.medication} = "Ticagrelor" then {myTable.medication}`
- add a condition to the **Group** selection formula like: 
  `DistinctCount({@mandatory_meds})=2 and DistinctCount({@optional_meds})>=1`